# calling multiple functions one by one on a single click event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

say that i have three different functions and for each i have assigned a JSX onClick event. What I'am trying to achieve is to assign them on a single click event that execute them one by one in order

```
const saveData = () => {
//saves data
}

const clearData = () => {
//clears data
}

const loadData = () => {
//loads data
}
```

JSX code:

```
<button onClick={saveData}>Save</button>
<button onClick={clearData}>Clear</button>
<button onClick={loadData}>onLoad</button>
```

here is what i want to do

```
const multipleFunc = () => {
saveData()
clearData()
loadData()

}

<button onClick={multipleFunc}>onLoad</button>
```

so I want to execute them all in the order I have describe inside `multipleFunc` should i do async await or what do you suggest?

Comment: what you just have there looks fine - what's the problem?

Comment: are those functions like you've described, or are they returning promises?

Comment: @RobinZigmond when i click `multipleFunc` then `saveData` and  `clearData` execute just fine but if i want `loadData` to work i need to click again `multipleFunc`.I just want to do all at once on a single click

Comment: sounds like there's a bug in your implementation of one or more of those functions then. Or perhaps they're asynchronous, so `loadData` is being executed before the actual saving of the data has been done. In which case as the answer below has stated, using `async/await` is the easiest way, assuming the functions actually return promises. Really there's nowhere near enough detail in your questions to know what the problem might be.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if all your functions are synchronized you dont need the async await syntax:

```js
const multipleFunc = () => {
saveData()
clearData()
loadData()
}
```

If some of your inner functions are async (returning promise) and you want to wait for the function to finish then add async await:

```js
const multipleFunc = async () => {
await saveData()
//Non async function
clearData()
await loadData()
}
```

For either case, you functions will run by orders but if you want to wait for async function to finish you need to use the await keyword